# How many facets can $\{\|D^T x\|_1\leq 1\}$ have?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, convex-polytopes

$\newcommand{\RR}{\mathbb{R}}$Consider $x\in\RR^n$ and $D\in \RR^{n\times p}$ with $p\geq n$ and full rank. My question is:

> How many facets can the polytope $ \{x\in\RR^n\ :\ \|D^T x\|_1\leq 1\}$ have?

For sure the number is exponential in $n$ as is shown by $D = I$ with $2^n$ facets. But how is the scaling in $p$?

A more computational variant of the question is:

> For what $r$ can you find a $B\in \RR^{n\times r}$ such that $\|D^T x\|_1 = \|B^T x\|_\infty$ for all $x$?

The existence of such a matrix $B$ is clear: The set $\{\|D^T x\|_1\leq 1\}$ is a centrally symmetric polytope and hence, is an intersection of halfspaces each of which appears two times with opposite sign. The vectors that define the halfspaces form the matrix $B$. Moreover, a minimal $r$ implies that the number of facets is $2r$. Of course it would also be helpful to know the number of vertices–

Some experiments show that one can not get an arbitrarily large number of facets when $n$ is fixed. For $n=2$ one can get $2p$ many faces by putting the $p$ roots of unity into the matrix $D$ and I guess this is best possible.

Comment: Regarding your second question: do you expect such $r$ and $B$ to exist. The $\ell^1$ and $\ell^{\infty}$ ball are so different (they are in fact dual to each other) that I cannot imagine such construction.

Comment: @CristóbalGuzmán Sure: both functionals are positively homogeneous, hence determined by their 1-levelset. Moreover, the set $\{\|D^Tx\|_1\leq 1\}$ is a centrally symmetric polytope, hence described by an intersection of finitely many half spaces, each of these appearing two times with opposite signs. Sets of this kind can be described as $\{\|B^Tx\|_\infty\leq 1\}$.

Comment: Your first question is equivalent to asking how many facets a cs polytope can have, that is obtained by cutting off bits from the unit cube using $p$ pairs of hyperplanes, right? This is probably a difficult problem given that even for general cs polytopes we don't know of many extremal results. You might want to start by looking at [this](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1106.0449v3.pdf) article by Barvinok et al. and references given there. They only cover the general case though.

Comment: @eins6180: Not quite. I am especially interested in the scaling in $p$ and the one constraint $\|D^Tx\|_1\leq 1$ can be formulated as $2^p$  inequalities (doing case distinction over the absolute values in the the sum). However, in the construction I did usually many of these inequalities are inactive…  I also guessed that this problem may be hard but had the hope that the special construction of the polytope as a kind of distorted one-norm would make the problem simpler…

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean unit cube but rather cross polytope in my comment above. Is it clear that not every combinatorial type of a cs polytope can be realized under your constraints?

Comment: In dimension two I couldn't get more than $2p$ facets. But that does not answer your question… But wait: What do you mean by combinatorial type?

Comment: Here is a slight simplification: Since the geometry of that polytop -- let's call it $P_D$ -- does not change under multiplication with $S\in GL_n$, the number of facets of $P_D$ equals the number of facets of $P_{S^tD}$. Since the $\ell^1$-norm is invariant under permutation and sign change of the vector entries, the number of facets also equals the number of facets of $P_{S^t D Q}$ for each signed permutation matrix $Q$. Therefore one can wlog assume that $D$ has the form $( 1_{n\times n} | M )$ for some $M\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times (p-n)}$.